# Getting starting with phone gap with cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I know this is very basic question , but i want to start with phone gap ,and i have no ideas about it. so i started with phone gap official site .

but i am so confuse there is not straight forward way to start. and i also did googling and find some nice tutorial but all is so old .

I am confuse with Cordova . before it we have to only install phone gap Dmg and it show in our Xcode but now it it very confusing

there are some command on site to install like

install

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Usages

```
$ phonegap create my-app
$ cd my-app
$ phonegap run android
```

but cant move forward here
Please suggest some tutorial with latest SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat broad, but I'll try to help. Working with PhoneGap involves a few steps. You want to begin by installing a mobile SDK. This is used by PhoneGap to create applications and which you pick is up to you. Android is the most cross platform, but on Mac, iOS is a bit easier. The platform guides (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides) walk you through the entire process. You should get that setup first.

Then, installing PhoneGap is as you said - one npm install. npm is a Node.js tool, but you don't have to know Node at all. Just install it so you have the npm tool, then literally just type in what they said.

At that point, you can use the PG CLI to create projects. The general process is:

make a new project - phonegap create foo
add platform support (based on what you install - phonegap local platform add android
add plugins that you may need
then send to an emulator - phonegap run android --emulator

If this doesn't make sense, then I'd recommend narrowing down your question a bit.